# How do I find help in the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

How do I find the help page from the stack exchange app? Mind, the mobile app. Not the browser version.

The only way I've accessed it so far is clicking on links put in the comments for other new members. I'm sure I could find it on the browser version but there has to be some way to find it in the app right?[image: added image of my screen]

Comment: You might want to ask this on the site for questions general to the network, [meta.se]. That would seem more likely to be seen by people who know the answer. We can migrate the question if you want; just "flag" your question for moderator attention and request migration.

Comment: Is this the iOS app?  I want to confirm before migrating.  (If I'd been a little faster I would have cancelled my edit while awaiting your response.)

Comment: No Google Play app for your help it takes me awhile because I am at  work  since I originally posted this this morning.

Comment: Interesting -- I wonder why your Android app looks different from mine.  Ok, I've edited the title to say Android and will migrate for you as you requested.

Comment: Long time SE Android app user here, and sorry to disappoint you, but there's *no* help center on the mobile app.